# Ability to create questions with vote or comment or both disabled

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, voting, down-votes

I am sure that many questions are not posted because the user has a fear of downvoters. It is true, because many people give downvotes only because of a small grammar error, or a method of programming that they don't like, or because the user posted a question that has a similar one in another place, even if it asks more information than the another similar question.

But the most important case for that is the new users. Beginner programmers that don't really know how to write good code. The people don't understand that and just downvote and shout out *"do not use css inline style on the html!!!"* for example.

The question is the prejudice that users sometimes have. Having the option of disabling votes  would mean you will be not traumatized if your question is totally non-sense to other people.

Comment: Downvoting doesn't happen because people don't understand how to code. It happens because people don't know how to ask a good question.

Comment: What exactly would be the point of down vote if bad questions couldn't be downvoted

Comment: If your question is nonsense, then nobody can answer and therefore it is not a useful question.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Are you really, positively, definitely *sure* downvotes result in users being *traumatized*?

Comment: Please note that on meta down votes can indicate disagreement

Comment: What is happening with your question score and it being "proof" of the issue is a tautology. People are **strongly disagreeing** with the proposal, hence the downvotes, as is normal for Meta.

Comment: There is a parallel in that the proposal is nonsense.

Comment: Sorry if this traumatizes you, but **do not use code formatting for highlighting something that isn't code!!!**

Comment: Sadly it looks like people have **absolutely no problem** with asking bad, unclear and incomplete questions.

Comment: @RichardTingle you can comment the question asking better formatting or something like that, but removing user reputation just for mistakes is too bad!

Comment: But that's the point of reputation - you only keep it if you are reputable for not making stupid mistakes. In real life if you start to say gibberish you will be less reputable too.

Comment: But if i really need a answer and i dont really know how to create a "good question" and i create a little poor question and it is a lot downvoted, then the people will most times refuse to answer it or to comment asking for more info etc. i see that all day

Comment: If you really need an answer but don't know how to ask, you can hire a contractor. Or use chat, if it fits the room that allows it (read the room rules first).

Comment: Getting you the answer is incidental. The goal of the site was always creating a knowledge base, and allowing terrible questions is counter to that goal.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Exactly, if you ask a bad question why would people answer it. For free, in their own time

Comment: And please don't use chat for asking terrible questions.

Comment: im not talking about allow terrible questions, im only talking about to do not allow downvoting on them, but they can be flagged to be deleted.

Comment: So getting their question deleted is somehow less "traumatising" than downvotes...?

Comment: @PauloRoberto So they get no feedback at all, just waiting, hoping for their answer then BAM closed

Comment: @RichardTingle I do it. Because i am a person that help the people that needs help, not the people that already know something.

Comment: yes @CatPlusPlus totally.

Comment: Downvotes allow the OP to see that he needs to improve his question.

Comment: Maybe some argumentation for that, because it really makes no sense?

Comment: Also don't take internet points so seriously, your life does NOT depend on them.

Comment: Do you really believe that imaginary internet points are more important than quality (and honest feedback about lack of thereof)?

Comment: @RichardTingle but obviously the user need to get a message in the inbox telling why the question was deleted, its better than lose a thing that you earned helping another people

Comment: @PauloRoberto Ok, so on the one hand I've got my critical question that I need answered for a project that needs to be finished today that is unclear but I don't realise it. On the other hand I have 20 internet points to lose

Comment: no @CatPlusPlus but it should have another ways to alert the user that the question is bad, instead of just removing a reputation from him that he earned sometimes hardly and sometimes losing a lot of time

Comment: @PauloRoberto And what would you say reputation means?

Comment: You get ~~points~~ for contributing to the site. Contributing is either asking questions or answering them. You do either good, you get points. You do either bad, you lose points. That's what points mean. Also, they don't mean anything and you should stop caring about them.

Comment: @PauloRoberto if you cannot handle a downvote than you shouldn't be on SO. Seriously, you're taking this way too seriously.  Its a meaningless number.

Comment: If no downvotes, how else could we discourage posting bad questions? I mean, if instead of downvotes anyone with 15+ rep could cast a delete vote on those, it might make some sense ;)

Comment: @RichardTingle you are ridiculing me, saying that. I am saying that can have another ways that dont make the user lose lose what the user got from good things.

Comment: Its also worth noting that downvotes are -2, whereas upvotes are +5 or +10, so it's balanced such that if you contribute at all positively you'll be moving in the positive direction

Comment: @PauloRoberto I'm sorry you feel that way. I'm only attempting to have a debate regarding a feature of the site

Comment: I am just trying to say a thing, but i cant express myself properly, you people are understanding my question wrong.

Comment: Well if many people understand you the same wrong way, probably that's you being unclear, and not readers being unreceptive. Obligatory [xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/1028/) ;) Also, [this might be interesting for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/225745).

Comment: @PauloRoberto If we are misunderstanding then this is the feedback I was talking about; edit your question to make it clear

Comment: im talking about something like: Bad Questions: 50 - Good Questions: 100 - Bad Answers - 30 - Good Answers - 50, the user dont loses good question or good answer points when doing a bad question or answer, but it get a mark on the question "this question was marked by a bad question by the following users" : bla,bla,bla

Comment: What does that equation mean, what are the numbers

Comment: @Mołot i liked this question, it is exactly what i feel

Comment: @PauloRoberto Also, If people endlessly post bad questions it poisons a community and then there are no answers for anyone, that is why the system exists as it does

Comment: @RichardTingle for the thousand time, i do not want to keep bad answers, i just want to create another way to punish it, and not by removing a good reputation scored by helping another people :)

Comment: @PauloRoberto But your punishment seems far more harsh; sudden unexpected deletion

Comment: recommended reading: [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: This suggestion is status-declined and people keep downvoting it, why?

Comment: @PauloRoberto like I said on your other post, the more you try to avoid downvotes, the more they come.  Specifically when you edit the post, it bumps it to the top of the page.  If you stop trying to edit that phrase it, it will fall off the front page sooner and be long forgotten.

Comment: Something worth noting - I've downvoted plenty, but I don't think I've **ever** downvoted because of horrendous spelling, grammar, formatting or coding style (never mind *minor* problems) (and I'm sure most people can say something similar). "Posting a question that has a similar one in another place" is often accompanied by showing a lack of research effort (which is a reason for downvoting) and asking more information about a question should typically be done with a comment or a bounty. If you have some specific cases you'd like to point out, we'd happily tell you what's wrong with them.

Comment: They should make it like YouTube, where you can disable rating on your videos.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Voting is an important feedback mechanism for stack exchange:

- Voting lets users know if their question is being well recieved; if its being badly recieved they are unlikely to get the answer they need. As such they need to know so they can update their question
- Voting lets stack exchange know if their question is being well recieved; if a user keeps posting bad questions they need to be stopped to avoid poisoning the community

Comments are even more critical; they give detailed feedback, perhaps asking questions about unclear elements. Without those questions it is likely the question will never be answered.

### Without feedback the user cannot improve

Without these things, this feedback, a user will simply sit and wait for their question to be answered until is is simply forgotten or closed

### Meaning of reputation

Reputation is a mark of how much the community trusts a user. Asking bad questions reduces that trust and so their reputation goes down; without this the number becomes meaningless.

### Prevention of users posting many bad questions

Ultimately bad questions drive away experts, they need to be avoided either by improvement or by closure. Reputation is one of the driving forces encouraging improvement, ensuring a good experience for all

Answer (score 2):

### Comments are important.

While I could answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280917/how-can-i-get-the-code) question with something like "Use find/grep/glob/ls/whatever", it does not help. My answer can not solve the problem that the asker has *because I don't understand what he is trying to archive*.

The best things that can now happen to such a post is:

- Delete it. (Downvotes are not longer imporant)
- Improving it. But because only the OP knows what he want to archive, only the OP can do that.

The question that the OP stated might sound reasonable for him (Note: not everyone is able to read his own question/answer and detect missing information - I try that at least). The only way to point that out **without comments** are answers (and a generic close reason). And answers are not intended to substitute a comment.

Comment: The example question is not the best, but one of the recently closed questions - Qick'n'Dirty find. Feel free to replace the example with something else.